# Did Abraham separate with Sarah after sending away Ishmael?

Tags: genesis, abraham, sacrifice, isaac

The last time Sarah is with Abraham is when she sent away Ishmael.It is said this grieved Abraham so much

Genesis 21:10-11 ESV

> So she said to Abraham, “Cast out this slave woman with her son, for the son of this slave woman shall not be heir with my son Isaac.”  And the thing was very displeasing to Abraham on account of his son.

The next chapter deals only with Isaac and Abraham when he offered Isaac at Mount Moriah and there is no mention of Sarah

Genesis 22:1-2 ESV

> After these things God tested Abraham and said to him, “Abraham!” And he said, “Here am I.”  He said, “Take your son, your only son Isaac, whom you love, and go to the land of Moriah, and offer him there as a burnt offering on one of the mountains of which I shall tell you.”

It is only in chapter 23 that she is mentioned to have died at Kiriath Arba in Hebron

Genesis 23:2 ESV

> Sarah died at Kiriath-arba (that is, Hebron) in the land of Canaan, and Abraham went in to mourn for Sarah and to weep for her.

Prior to the death of Sarah Abraham is said to have been living in Beer-sheba

Genesis 21:33-34 ESV

> Abraham planted a tamarisk tree in Beersheba and called there on the name of the LORD, the Everlasting God.  And Abraham sojourned many days in the land of the Philistines.

There is a curious statement which says Abraham went ot mourn his dead in Hebron

Genesis 23:2 ESV

> And Sarah died at Kiriath-arba (that is, Hebron) in the land of Canaan, and Abraham went in to mourn for Sarah and to weep for her.

Did Abraham live with Sarah when she died?

Answer (score 1):

The OP is not the first to observe this "separation" of Abraham and Sarah in their story.

However, I suggest that this marriage separation occurred after Abraham was instructed to offer Isaac as a sacrifice on Mt Moriah (near Jerusalem) as the OP's selected history shows.  It was after the "sacrifice of Isaac" (Gen 22) and not the banishment if Ishmael, that Sarah lived in Kiriath-Arba (that is, Hebron).

This separation was probably for at least two reasons:

- Sarah was very angry with Abraham for such an act of child sacrifice, even though it was aborted
- Abraham was living in Beersheba, a long way from Hebron and perhaps, Sarah wanted to be closer to where Isaac was "sacrificed" to prevent a repetition.

[I pause to not that Mt Moriah was later called Mt Zion where the temple was built. 2 Chron 3:1.]

It was later, after the death of Sarah (Gen 23), that both Abraham and Isaac lived in Hebron (Gen 35:27, 37:14).

Answer (score 0):

It is curious about the separate living situation of Sarah and Abraham. There may be more than one potential reason. The incident with Isaac could be one explanation, that she was angry and left, and that they lived apart from that point on until her death. Another may be that Sarah’s advanced age took it’s toll on her, her health failed, she was incapacitated, and then needed full-time care until her death.

If their living apart was health related, that could have two explanations. It may have been due to the Isaac episode affecting her health. Or else it could have been that her health failed due to her age alone, and had nothing to do with what Abraham nearly did to Isaac.

Either way, Abraham had the resources to ensure Sarah was well cared for in her final days, and he ensured a proper burial as well. Scripture doesn’t specify the reasons they lived apart, so these theories are conjecture.